# Is a night VFR rating a prerequisite for an EASA CPL?

Tags: easa-regulations, pilot-certification, cpl

I'm wondering if I need to pay for a night VFR (NVFR) rating or can I just do my time building, ME, IR and exams to get a CPL? Is it possible without an NVFR rating?

Answer (score 1):

According to FCL.610 (IR - Pre-requisites) you need to have a PPL or CPL and a night rating to apply for the IR.
If you do not have the IR, the night flying qualification (NFQ) is no requirement to start training for the CPL. According to the AMC appendix 3 of the Notice of proposed Amendment (NPA) No. 2008-17B night flying is part of a training course for the CPL.And FCL.315 states, that the applicant for a CPL shall complete a trining according to the appendix 3, cited above.

SO: If you have the IR, you should also have the NFQ but you do not need the NFQ to start training for the CPL.
However, you only need 5 hrs night flying to get the NFQ and there is no examination, i.e. the FI rates your skill.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (at least in 2019). The mentioned in the previous answer FCL.610 (IR - Pre-requisites) (see [Part-FCL](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Part-FCL.pdf)) clearly states that for IR you need NVFR only if you are not going to fly at night:

> Applicants for an IR shall:
>
> (a) hold: (1) at least a PPL in the appropriate aircraft category,
> and:
>
> (i) the privileges to fly at night in accordance with FCL.810, if
> the IR privileges will be used at night; or
>
> (ii) an ATPL in another
> category of aircraft;
>
> or (2) a CPL, in the appropriate aircraft
> category;
>
> ...

So for IR it it possible, but you will not be able to fly at night even though you might have a valid IR.

But the CPL is a different story. If you are following a modular course (and from your question I can conclude that it can be only a modular course - integrated one does not allow you to decide whether you want NVFR or not), you must undergo 5 night instructional hours during your CPL training if you hold a valid IR. it is stated in the *Appendix 3 -Training courses for the issue of a CPL and an ATPL*, part *E. CPL modular course -Aeroplanes*, subpart "Flying training", #10.

So when you finish your CPL and IR during the modular course, your will have a NVFR somehow. It is not just 'time building' though, there are some requirements about dual time.